# Mongoose: cyclic dependency detected

Tags: express, mongoose

I've got an Express/Mongoose app that keeps throwing "cyclic dependency detected" errors at me. I've localized the problem to one of these files.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://username:MY.PASSWORD@cluster0-6vlss.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true');

require('./models/Users');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
```

**routes/users.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var User = mongoose.model('User');

router.route('/user/:id')
    .get((req, res, next) => {
        User.findById(req.params.id, (err, user) => {
            if (err) return next(err);
            res.json(user);
        });
    });
```

**models/Users.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: String,
    username: {type: String, unique: true},
    hash: String,
    salt: String,
    chats: Array
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Hopefully I condensed my code well enough. Could somebody point to my screw-up?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. In app.js, dbconfig is an object that *stores* the database URI string. I called "dbconfig" directly instead of "dbconfig.url". Everything's good now.

Comment: Hello , I am having the same problrm what do you mean you called dbconfig" directly instead of "dbconfig.url".? Can you please show me a code example?